# Android Studio java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method encodeHexString

Tags: java, android, apache

I haven't any idea how to fix this problem, and also I don't need to use another methods, how to correctly import apache commons, io, log4j libraries?

**UPD:**

problem was solved, I just changed name of directort for commons

```
  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                              Process: idocs.ciphered, PID: 9404
                                                              java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method encodeHexString([B)Ljava/lang/String; in class Lorg/apache/commons/codec/binary/Hex; or its super classes (declaration of 'org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex' appears in /system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.boot.jar)
                                                                  at idocs.ciphered.utils.CryptoHelper.hex(CryptoHelper.java:149)
                                                                  at idocs.ciphered.utils.CryptoHelper.random(CryptoHelper.java:136)
                                                                  at idocs.ciphered.utils.CryptoHelper.encrypt(CryptoHelper.java:91)
                                                                  at idocs.ciphered.Main.onCreate(Main.java:42)
                                                                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6904)
                                                                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1136)
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3266)
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3415)
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:229)
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1821)
                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7331)
                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Are u using android studio then using this one

        compile group: 'de.mindpipe.android', name: 'android-logging-log4j', version: '1.0.3'
    compile group: 'log4j', name: 'log4j', version: '1.2.17'

Are u using eclipse then 

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/a/Downloadandroidlogginglog4j103jar.htm

this link from download jar

add externel lib of ur project and check of it apply
```

Comment: yeap fixed, just download source code from here https://blog.goddchen.de/2013/03/apache-commons-codec-android-compatible/ and rename package and it's work